# json error on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, haml

I have the following action on my controller:

```
def bank_response
        @booking = Booking.where(order_number: params[:order]).first
        if(!@booking.Ds_Response.nil?)
            respond_to do |format|
            format.json {  render json: @booking, success: 200  }
          end
        end
    end
```

on my Newview I have the following code:

```
setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "/bank_response/#{@order_number}",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data: {"order" : "#{@order_number}"},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
          alert("success");
        },
        error: function(result) {
          alert("error");
        }
      });
    },10000);
```

also I have a the bank_response view like this:

```
{  "booking" : "#{@booking.to_s}" }
```

But I always get error 500 from my New view.

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/bank_response/609nrhqlewbi
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
```

Thanks for your help

UPDATE - RAILS SERVER

---

> MultiJson::LoadError at
>   /bank_response/ffgs1d79aatc===================================================>
>   795: unexpected token at 'order=ffgs1d79aatc'multi_json (1.8.2)
>   lib/multi_json/load_error.rb, line
>   6-------------------------------------------------------`ruby    1 
>   module MultiJson    2     class LoadError < StandardError    3
>
>   attr_reader :data    4       def initialize(message='', backtrace=[],
>   data='')    5         super(message)>   6
>
>   self.set_backtrace(backtrace)    7         @data = data    8       end
>   9     end   10     DecodeError = LoadError # Legacy support   11
>
>   end`App backtrace-------------Full backtrace-------------- -
>   multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json/load_error.rb:6:in `initialize' -
>   multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:122:in`rescue in load' -
>   multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:119:in `load' - activesupport
>   (3.2.13) lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:15:in`decode' -
>   actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:47:in
>   `parse_formatted_parameters' - actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:17:in`call' -
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in
>   `call' - rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in`context'
>   - rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call' - actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in`
>   call' - actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call' -
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   _run__4308745349437725987__call__4526229337647608189__callbacks' -
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback' - activesupport (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_call_callbacks' -
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks' - actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call' - actionpack
>   (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call' -
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`
>   call' - better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in
>   `protected_app_call' - better_errors (1.0.1)
>   lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in`better_errors_call' -
>   better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call' -
>   actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in`call' -
>   actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call' -
>   railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in`call_app' - railties
>   (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call' -
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in`
>   tagged' - railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call' -
>   quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in`
>   call_with_quiet_assets' - actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call' - rack
>   (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call' - rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' - activesupport (3.2.13)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call' - rack
>   (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call' - actionpack (3.2.13)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in`call' - railties
>   (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call' - railties (3.2.13)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:223:in`call' - rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' - railties (3.2.13)
>   lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`call' - thin (1.5.1)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process' - thin (1.5.1)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in`pre_process' - thin (1.5.1)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process' - thin (1.5.1)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in`receive_data' - eventmachine (1.0.3)
>   lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run' - thin (1.5.1)
>   lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in`start' - thin (1.5.1)
>   lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start' - rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in`run' - rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start' - railties (3.2.13)
>   lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in`start' - railties (3.2.13)
>   lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>' - railties
>   (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`' -
>   script/rails:6:in `<main>' - script/rails:0:in`'

UPDATE SOLVED

---

Guys, my problem was the type: "POST", because I'm making a "GET"

Thanks anyway.

Comment: any error message on your console?

Comment: @worldask only  POST http://localhost:3000/bank_response/ffgs1d79aatc 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: take a look to your rails server screen

Comment: @worldask I just posted the rails server screen

Answer (score 0):

to respond with you'll have to do somethiing liek this:

```
format.json do
    render json: {
      booking_attr: @booking.attr,
      booking_second_attr: @booking_second_attr,
      id: @booking.id
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks jose, but I think I have another error, because if I go to my  http://localhost:3000/bank_response/ORDERNUMBER.json I get the following {"Ds_Amount":"2500","Ds_AuthorisationCode":"508380","Ds_Card_Country":"724","Ds_Card_Type":null,"Ds_ConsumerLanguage":"1","Ds_Currency":"978","Ds_Date":"22/09/2014","Ds_Hour":"13:37", etc etc etc} so I think I'm sending the correct information, but my problem is when I try to do the same using ajax